# Selenium Exception with no stack trace (grunt / protractor / selenium)

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, protractor, karma-jasmine

I try to run grunt test, and Selenium exits without closing the browser. I am unable to see where the exception is coming from.

```
grunt test
Running "protractor_webdriver:start" (protractor_webdriver) task
Starting Selenium server
Started Selenium server: http://127.94.0.1:4444
Running "protractor:projecttest" (protractor) task
[10:16:33] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[10:16:33] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Session created: count=1, browserName=chrome
......Exception thrown: Going to shut down the Selenium server
Shutting down Selenium server: http://127.94.0.1:4444
Shut down Selenium server: http://127.94.0.1:4444 (OKOK)
Fatal error: 10:16:45.529 WARN - Exception thrown
```

All of my tests are passing. I even added logs to prove the final test passes and exits without exception.

I tried to up my logging from "dots" to "progress" but it doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: happens to me as well with phantomjs :